# PHP syntax in Sublime Text very slow

Tags: php, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

My Sublime Text 3's PHP syntax highlighting causes the editor to become extremely slow. And it's proportional to the amount of code in the current file.

It's only with PHP. As soon as I switch to JavaScript syntax, it become super responsive again!

I don't even have any Linters installed, just JSON linter, none for PHP AFAIK.

How do I figure out what's causing PHP syntax highlighting to make the editor slow and sliggish?

Comment: Post on the forum and someone may help debugging the issue. https://forum.sublimetext.com/